# ksoap2 (Android) and GZIPped BasicHttpBinding

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2, basichttpbinding

I want to consume a BasicHttp WCF web service with ksoap2 that is compressed by GZIP.

Is there a way to do this in the Android version of ksoap2 (http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) or is there another way?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/6717165/779408

Answer (score 1):

I have create a class that extend the HTTPTransportSe and overrode the call() method and added this line to the code (taken from here https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-j2se/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.java)

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","[Here you have to put the encoding]");
```

Then when I get the InputStream I use the retHeaders variable to check if there's the encoding.

```
if (retHeaders != null){
            Iterator it = retHeaders.iterator();
            boolean found = false;
            String encoding = "";
            while (it.hasNext()){
                HeaderProperty temp = (HeaderProperty) it.next();
                if (temp.getKey().contentEquals("content-encoding")){
                    found = true;
                    encoding = temp.getValue();
                }
            }
            if (found){
                is = new GZIPInputStream(is, new Inflater(true));
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                while (true) {
                    int rd = is.read(buf, 0, 256);
                    if (rd == -1)
                        break;
                    bos.write(buf, 0, rd);
                }
                bos.flush();
                buf = bos.toByteArray();
               is.close();
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
            }
        }
        parseResponse(envelope, is);
```

And then you have to pass the "is" to the parser.
If there's a better way to code it I will happy to know about it. .))

Comment: How about providing this or something along these lines as a patch for the project. I could pull it in..

Comment: This is now in master of ksoap2-android and will fix issue 103 and become part of the next release (2.6.5 or so)